# iOS 7 UIWebView rotation to landscape orientation add some bar

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview, autolayout, landscape, ios7

I have such situation, all screens in my application is in portrait mode, but I have one screen that could be in both orientations. On iOs 6 everything works fine but on iOS 7 when I rotate to landscape I am receive such situation as shown at the bottom. Big black bar at the bottom of screen.:

[image: iOS 7 landscape orientation] 
I want to make full screen and I have try self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone; but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I think this problem is related to this other one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947872/ios7-added-new-whitespace-in-uiwebview-removing-uiwebview-whitespace-in-ios7/23097605#23097605

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the flag (use autolayout) in the interface builer document

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with tab bar when I rotate my device, to solve that issue I have implement next code in my category that works with hiding and showing tab bar on rotation:

```
 @implementation UITabBarController (HideBar)

- (void)showTabBar:(BOOL)show
{
    UITabBar* tabBar = self.tabBar;
    if (show != tabBar.hidden)
        return;
    UIView* subview = [self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
    CGRect frame = subview.frame;
    frame.size.height += tabBar.frame.size.height * (show ? -1 : 1);
    subview.frame = frame;
    tabBar.hidden = !show;
}
```

I just add next code at the bottom of the method:

```
 if (IOS_7) {
    CGRect tabBarFrame = tabBar.frame;
    tabBarFrame.size.height = show ? TABBAR_HEIGHT : 0;
    tabBar.frame = tabBarFrame;
}
```