# UIWebview scrollview changes contentsize for no reason

Tags: uiwebview, ios7, scrollview, xcode5, contentsize

I have a uiviewcontroller which loads a uiwebview. When the uiviewcontroller loads the uiwebview everything is done correctly. But when one navigates away and returns back and the uiwebview is not loaded, it is displayed differently. The uiwebview scrollview's contentsize height changes by 64px, it gets higher.

When it is loaded for the first it looks like this
[image]

When one returns back to the view, this is what happens

[image]

I hope I was able to make my problem understandable. If more details are necessary, I am able to give more. Thank you

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the same problem when I press the home button and go back to my app. Then I get the same contentSize change as you get.

Comment: @Thermometer I could fix it, but not in a clean way. The appearance is not as awful anymore, because there isn't this empty space between navigationBar and uiWebView. Still the scrollbar does not touch the navigationBar.

Comment: I am sure this can be solved in a better way, but this is the code I used for this is                                           - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)aScrollView
{
    if(aScrollView.contentOffset.y < 0)
    {
        [aScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    }
    else
    {
        [aScrollView setContentOffset: CGPointMake(0, aScrollView.contentOffset.y)];
    }
}

Comment: @Thermometer have you found any fix? can you please share it

Comment: My fix was not really a fix :(. I loaded my `UIWebView` in my `UIViewController`'s view in a `UITabbarController` before. I now load it in a `UIViewController` that I show modally, which fixes the problem for me. I have asked a question about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262938/uiwebview-changes-contentsize-on-ios-7-after-coming-back-from-background), which didn't really get a valid answer, so I just restructured it to fix the problem.

Comment: Here is another discussion of the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947872/ios7-added-new-whitespace-in-uiwebview-removing-uiwebview-whitespace-in-ios7

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, try this code in your `viewDidLoad` method.

```
if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:)])
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this.
    - (void) viewDidLoad
    {
         [super viewDidLoad];
         self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
    }

Comment: This doesn't seem to help :(