# UIWebView changes contentSize on iOS 7 after coming back from background

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview, ios7

**The Problem:**

I have a `UIWebView` between my `UINavigationBar` and `UITabBar`. On iOS 7, when the app enters background and comes back again, it seems as if the `contentSize` property of the `UIWebView` changes so that there is a white block above it.

After monitoring the `contentSize` of the `UIWebView`, when the application enters foreground (I check it by observing the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`), it has 49 substracted from it's height.

**Screenshot (redacted sensitive info):**
[image: Redacted version of the screenshot]

**My Settings:**

I am using a `UIWebView` in my `UIViewController` that is embedded in a `UITabBarViewController` that is embedded in a `UINavigationController`. I am using Storyboards and having "Adjust Scroll View Insets", "Resize View From NIB" and "Extend Edges Under Tob Bars" on. On the `UIWebView` I have unchecked "Scales Page To Fit". I am not doing anything in the `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear` methods. I tested it on iOS 6, and the problem doesn't occur there. Also, I am not using auto-layout.

**Relevant Code:**

```
self.webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
self.webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;
self.webView.scalesPageToFit = NO;
```

**After monitoring contentSize & frame in `viewDidAppear` & `appHasGoneInForeground`:**

Frame goes from 320x455 to 320x455
contentSize goes from 320x504 to 320x455

Does anyone have an idea what I am missing here and/or why this happens? Thanks for your time!

Comment: the issue comes in iphone5 ?

Comment: Yeah, the screenshot is from the iPhone 5. Although I just tested it in the simulator for the 3,5" screen, and the problem also occurs there

Comment: set screen size window bounds not for hard code

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? I do not hardcode my views for 3,5" or 4" screens.

Comment: how did to set uiwebview size

Comment: I am using storyboards, not setting size in code.

Comment: do you check what happened in iPhone5 the storyboard. the bottom page it will small icon it check both screen layout checking at moments.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42121/discussion-between-thermometer-and-idev)

Comment: I think you are using auto layout,please check your constraints.

Comment: I tried recreating this issue and couldn't.  Do you think you can post an Xcode project that contains minimum code to reproduce this issue?

Comment: hey mate please see my answer below thats the only solution to ios7 defined under apple guidance for ios7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"I am using a UIWebView in my UIViewController that is embedded in a UITabBarViewController that is embedded in a UINavigationController".

This is not supported by Apple. [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH6-SW1)

> ...the order of containment is important; only certain arrangements
>   are valid. The order of containment, from child to parent, is as
>   follows:
>
> Content view controllers, and container view controllers that have
>   flexible bounds (such as the page view controller)
>
> Navigation view controller
>
> Tab bar controller
>
> Split view controller

I would try a simpler and valid container arrangement first to and see if it resolves the issue. Note that even if you solve this specific issue, if you keep using your hierarchy you may still run into unexpected and possibly inconsistent UI issues.

Comment: Hmm, that would be a shame, but I will try to branch and restructure to swap the `UINavigationController` and `UITabBarController`to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: I restructured it to have it load modally in a `ViewController`. Now this problem doesn't occur. +1 for suggesting to restructure.

Comment: Glad I could help. I wish Apple would enforce in their SDK rules like the one I quoted from them, or at least warn when these rules are violated, instead of counting on us to know them by heart.

Answer (score 20):

Please try `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO` in webView's viewController.

automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets is new property in iOS7 SDK, and default value is YES.It can auto adjust viewController's scrollView in iOS7.You can get more information with google search.

I hope it can help you.

Comment: This should not be changing the content size.

Comment: Sorry, changing this property didn't help. Thanks for trying to help though

Comment: Thanks @mengxiangjian, saved me hours of debugging!

Comment: Fantastic! I struggled with this for a while (using auto layout). Now my web view's content fills the whole screen regardless of screen size. I unchecked the 'Adjust Scroll View Insets' of my view controller (not webview) option and problem solved.

Answer (score 6):

You can setContentSize or frame on:

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
```

set UIWebview in xib bottomscle

[image: Autorising]

other wise you can set

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;
self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars=NO;
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets=NO;
```

Comment: Setting my contentSize in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` did not fix the problem :(

Answer (score 4):

This is very strange behavior. Are you using AutoLayout? If you are, double check that your constraints ensure that the webView's edges are always equal to the ViewController's view edges.

If you aren't using AutoLayout, set the autoresizingMask such that the leading and trailing space are fixed:

```
webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

If this doesn't work, you can add a hack/workaround using KVO (please only use this as a last resort, because it's not good practice):

```
[view addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:0 context:NULL];
```

Then implement the method

```
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
```

and set the contentSize back to what it should be.

Comment: Awesome, I will try that and report back here! I am not using autoLayout by the way.

Comment: Explicitly setting the autoresizingMask didn't help. Very weird. I also tried your hack, which doesn't work either for me. I am checking if the contentsize is lower than the desired size in `- (void) observeValueForKeyPath` and then setting the contentSize to the right size. Do I need to use setNeedsLayout or something to actualize the changes? Because my NSLogs now dictate the correct contentSize after coming back in the app

Comment: @Thermometer have you also verified that the frame for the webview is correct? it could be that the frame is being modified.

Comment: Yeah the frame doesn't change.

Comment: I print the frame, inset and contentsize when the view is loaded in `viewDidAppear` and `appHasGoneInForeground` to see what the difference is. First the contentSize is 320x504 and frame is 320x455, the inset is 0. After coming back the contentSize is 320x455 and frame is 320x455, the inset stayed 0.

Comment: So the frame changes... You can hack that with KVO, or do some research as to why the frame is changing. Maybe make a subclass of UIWebView that overrides setters for the frame to see where it is being changed.

Comment: Where do you see the frame changing then? The frame size is the same before and after. Only the contentSize changes.

Comment: Oh, never mind. I got those numbers switched around in my head.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code (i know, that it's unsafe)

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
 {
   if(self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent == YES)
   {

    _webView.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(_webView.frame.origin.x, _webView.frame.origin.y - 54);

   }
 }
```

The number after the _webView.frame.origin.y

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't fix the problem. It still resizes after coming back to the app

Answer (score 1):

Hi mate please see image that would help you.

When you have the UIWebview or tableview please check the all the direction of auto resizing on the right of the UIwebview ( Size Inspector tab )
[image]

**And also you have to mention the Delta Y to -20 and Delta Height to 20 which is for iOS 7**

Comment: Sorry but I already have the autosizing with those settings. Adding the iOS 6/7 deltas did not work.

Comment: Hey mate don't add delta for iOS 6, add this only for iOS 7. For other version it would calculate by system.

Comment: The option is called "iOS 6/7 Deltas".. :P

Comment: lets have a conversation in a chat room

http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15038/ios-developer-family