# IOS -UIWebView - changes content size

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview

i am new to IOS programming. I am developing an ebook. I have a `UIWebView` below my top toolbar. on first page i am displaying the Book Picture. Problem is when i load the app first the book Picture displays fine but when i swipe back to the previous page until Book Picture displays again it shows white block above it. i think contentSize property of the UIWebView changes so that there is a white block above it. i don't know what should i do.
[image]

for example in this picture.there is a white block above it.

picture is copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262938/uiwebview-changes-contentsize-on-ios-7-after-coming-back-from-background)

Comment: hey i have your answer your question before, about adding subview in navigation bar. if you can hide that subview or disable that view from tool bar and test your app again an see if this problem still consist then then i ll tell you solution. just wana make sure problem is what i m thinking

Comment: u mean disable the uiWEBView right ? how can i disable it ?